# Kubernetes loadbalance between monolith and microservices

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

We have a K8 EKS cluster with ALB ingress controller and behind that, we have a graphql gateway. On the cluster there are two node groups, one microservices the other the remaining monolith. We have not fully completed pulling out all the services. We get some pretty high volume workloads and I need to scale up the monolith node group. How can I load balance traffic across node groups or namespaces? Or some other unthought-of solution.

Answer (score 1):

When your K8s-based application uses `services`, the traffic is load-balanced between the active pods of the target deployment. Kubernetes services are themselves the crudest form of load balancing traffic. In Kubernetes the most basic type of load balancing is load distribution. Kubernetes uses two methods of load distribution. Both of them are easy to implement at the dispatch level and operate through the kube-proxy feature.